# Check if different views touched at the same time

Tags: swift, uiview, touch, uitouch

I've few UIView on my ViewController
How can I check if all of them touched now? They are placed in different sides of screen and each of them must be touched by separated fingers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the touchesEnded delegate

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        startTouchPosition = touches.first?.locationInView(self)
        let touch = touches.first
        if let touchPoint = touch?.locationInView(self){
            for view in self.views{
                if(view.containsPoint(touchPoint)){

                }
            }
        }
    }
```